# how to set requirejs plugin in maven

Tags: maven, requirejs

I move my project from ubuntu to windows, and the requirejs plugin not work!

I just change the nodejs path

```
<nodeExecutable>C:/Program Files/nodejs/node</nodeExecutable>
```

And the maven return this

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.mcheely:requirejs-maven-plugin:2.0.0:o
ptimize (default) on project interactBack: r.js exited with an error. -> [Help 1
]
```

I have test my project by cmd , and it works fun!

```
node r.js -o app.build.js
```

What's the problem？

Comment: Just an educated guess, but wouldn't Windows need forward slashes in the path? I.e. "C:\Program Files\..."

Comment: I agree with that there must be something wrong with the path! but your guess is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer!

As is said by the author

```
nodeExecutable

An optional path to a nodejs executable. This should not be needed if node is in 
the system path as 'node' or 'nodejs';
```

So, just delete the  tag.